# Opencv Features2d: Similar Object Recognition

Tags: image-processing, opencv, feature-detection

I am using opencv in order to detect if two objects are similar or not. I applied certain methods available by opencv to purify the images for better recognition. As a result, I now have a vector of keypoints that I am interested in.

I gave these keypoints to siftfeaturedetector and the result was not satisfactory (it matched every pt in image 1 to all point in image 2). I used surf to compute descriptors and flann to match my already calculated keypoints.

Is there a way to let any featuredetector compare these 2 images with better results? Or maybe I should not use feature detectors (what is the alternative)?

The Images I am comparing have unique shapes (but not equal shapes) but different orientations and size.

Comment: As a starting point, you must include sample images that you are comparing. Also include the pre-processing you did, saying "certain methods ... to purify the images" actually says nothing.

Comment: I have a Database of images that contain different orientations and sizes. I retrieve each image and compare it with the input image. As for the pre-processing, I am using colors to detect the object in the input image; after that, I use laplace plus other techniques to make the image more clear. At this stage I have a bounding box of the object. Finally, I want to detect if this object has similar shape with the images in the database. Thus, color is not enough, I still need shape to make a better conclusion...

Comment: Now you have said nothing + epsilon. There is no question to be answered here.

Comment: Yeah, add example images and ideally code to reproduce your problem.